# Are judgments composed of paragraphs or sections?

Tags: legal-citation, notation

They seem to comprise numbered segments, but how are these referred to? Is there any conventional notation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will vary from judge to judge, and perhaps from case to case even for the same judge. The most common practicve might vary from court to court.

In the case of the US Supreme court, different decisions are organized in different ways. Some have sections labeled by numbers, some by letters, some by roman numbers, some by an outline hierarchy. Different opinions written by the same justice will be organized differently.

Similarly there is no consistent terminology for the divisions. When one p[art is referred to in another "section" seems most common, with "paragraph" being reserved for grammatical paragraphs, which are not usually numbered.

Comment: The modern standard for U.S. state courts is to denote grammatical paragraphs with numbered paragraphs with the number ¶ as part of an open source citation movement in which cases are denoted YEAR COURT-ABBREVIATION SEQUENTIAL-CASE-DECIDED-NUMBER-BY-COURT-IN-YEAR, ¶ number. Thus, for example, 2015 CO 32, ¶ 12 for paragraph 12 of the 32nd case decided by the Colorado Supreme Court in the year 2015. This paragraph numbering was implemented in recent years to eliminate the need to use West reporter page numbering for pinpoint citations.